# Formula in Classic Email Template ISBLANK

Tags: formula, email-template

I am trying to return custom text when a field is blank in my record using a classic email template. I am pulling my hair out. I have searched high and low with no luck. I am using this formula in the email template. This is not returning any results just come back without anything. Please help!

Association Partner:

```
{!IF(ISBLANK(Pro_Marketing_Product__c.Association_Partner__c) ,
     Pro_Marketing_Product__c.Association_Partner__c,
    'no')}
```

Comment: Is `Pro_Marketing_Product__c` a relationship field (lookup or master-detail)? If so, you need to use `__r` at the end to be able to grab data from a related record.

Comment: `__r` instead of `__c`. So `Pro_Marketing_Product__r.Association_Partner__c`

Comment: No the field is {!Pro_Marketing_Product__c.Association_Partner__c} and that alone returns the data from that field.